# Using ostream overloading on pointers to objects

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++14, auto, ostream

So, I have a struct `Bike`, which looks like this

```
struct Bike {
    std::string brand;
    std::string model;
    bool is_reserved;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream out, const Bike& b);
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream out, const Bike& b) {
    return out 
        << "| Brand: " << b.brand << '\n'
        << "| Model: " << b.model << '\n';
}
```

And another class `BikeRentalService`, which has a `std::vector<Bike*>` called `bikes_m`. This class also has a method `print_available_bikes()`, which is supposed to iterate over said `std::vector<Bike*>` and print each `Bike` by using the overloaded `operator<<` shown above. This method looks like that:

```
void BikeRentalService::print_available_bikes(std::ostream& out) {
    if (bikes_m.empty()) {
        out << "| None" << '\n';
    }
    else {
        for (auto bike : bikes_m) {
            if (!bike->is_reserved) {
                out << bike;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that using this function just prints out the addresses of those `Bike` objects. Dereferencing the objects before using `out <<` does not work either, Visual Studio says it can't reference `std::basic_ostream` because it is a "deleted function".
Writing the for loop as `(auto *bike : bikes_m)` does not change anything.

Comment: From your description, it's not clear to me if you tried `out << *bike;`.

Comment: Your `operator<<` needs to take `out` by reference. Then use `out << *bike;`. (Though I'm not seeing the point of using a `std::vector<Bike*>` in the first place.)

Comment: What else should I be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rigth way to overload the ostream operator is as follows:

```
struct Bike {
    std::string brand;
    std::string model;
    bool is_reserved;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Bike& b); // <- note passing out by reference
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Bike& b) {
    return out 
        << "| Brand: " << b.brand << '\n'
        << "| Model: " << b.model << '\n';
}
```

Also, as noted by @KyleKnoepfel you should change `out << bike;` to `out << *bike;` too.